# How to simplify this C# Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a better way to write this in vs2010 C#?

```
   public bool IsAccept()
    {
        //check the status is accept
        if (Status == null)
            return false;
        return Status.ToLower() == "accept";
    }

    public bool IsRefer()
    {
        //check the status is refer
        if (Status == null)
            return false;
        return Status.ToLower() == "refer";
    }


    public bool IsAnyReviewState()
    {
        if (IsAccept() || IsRefer())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Maybe a simplified way in C# 4 which I'm still learning.

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could this be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com instead of closed?

Answer (score 1):

you can use short-circuit evaluation to make the code a bit more precise. BTW. there is nothing C# 4 specific about this.

```
public bool IsAccept()
{
    //check the status is accept
    return Status != null && Status.ToLower() == "accept";
}

public bool IsRefer()
{
    //check the status is refer
    return Status != null && Status.ToLower() == "refer";
}


public bool IsAnyReviewState()
{
    return IsAccept() || IsRefer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For simple accessors like these, Property syntax is better than methods.
2. Use `String.Equals` or `String.IndexOf` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of doing `String.ToLower() ==`. Also if you absolutely must normalize strings, then use `String.ToUpperInvariant` as it preserves certain information that is lost when doing `ToLowerInvariant`, this affects non-Latin languages such as Turkish which has special behaviour of its I-like character.
3. Consider using `String.IsNullOrEmpty`
4. Remember that boolean operators return boolean values themselves, so you can simplify your `IsAnyReviewState` massively.

Here is how I would write your code:

```
public bool IsAccept {
    get {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty( this.Status ) ? false : this.Status.Equals("accept", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public bool IsRefer {
    get {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty( this.Status ) ? false : this.Status.Equals("refer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public bool IsAnyReviewState {
    get {
        return this.IsAccept || this.IsRefer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ternary operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like so:

```
  public bool IsAccept()
    {
        //check the status is accept
        return Status == null ? false : Status.ToLower() == "accept";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public bool IsAccept()
    {
      return (Status == null)?false:(Status.ToLower() == "accept");
    }
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public bool IsAnyReviewState()
{
    return new [] {"accept", "refer"}.Contains((Status??string.empty).ToString().ToLower())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer using `string.Equals` for string comparison. In the case of `IsAccept()`, I would write:

```
public bool IsAccept()
{
   return string.Equals(Status, "accept", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

This frees you from writing defensive `null`-checks and doesn't require `.ToLower()`.

*Less code := happy coder*

**edit**: does the `Status` property need to be a `string`? You could replace it for an enumeration maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As RvdK said, this question should be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Also, I'm not sure whether you are trying to make the code more compact or more readable.

If you're trying to make it more readable, the only thing that comes to mind is to modify the `return` statements.

For example, instead of

```
return Status.ToLower() == "accept";
```

consider

```
if(Status.ToLower() == "accept") 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```

Comment: This heavily depends on what you consider readable. I oppose to this, for instance, as I have to mentally check if the return true is in the true-path whereas in the short notation form I don't have that extra mental 'load'.

Comment: The primary reason I suggested what I suggested was because someone who is unfamiliar to coding might find it easier to understand what is going on. It's plausible that somebody might not realise that the `==` operator will return a boolean value which can be returned by a method.